# Why memory error for line-by-line reading of large file?

Tags: python, pandas, memory, large-data, large-files

I am careful enough to not load the large file into memory at once. I am rather reading it line-by-line. However, I can't figure out why I am getting a Memory error after certain lines (index: 32671363) are read?

The minimal example is below. I have tried the code with even larger files before and never received this error. There is a possibility that the file may be corrupted after index 32671363. But how can I find out the bad lines/characters or anything that's causing it (I can't just open the text file and see it since it is 14 GB!)? I tried printing each line on console but the output doesn't tell me anything (see below). Any suggestions of how to dig deep?

I tried pandas (reading data in chunks/data-frames), giving me a similar memory error at this index.

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f0:
    for i, line in enumerate(f0):
        if i > 32671360:
            print(i, repr(line))
        else:
            pass
```

**Sample Output**

```
32671361 '239,7449657815100,6998.258682,7449.502713\n'
32671362 '263,7449658092300,6998.258682,7449.502713\n'
32671363 '423,7449658212000,6998.258682,7449.502713\n'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "read_lst_line.py", line 48, in <module>
    for i, line in enumerate(f0):
MemoryError
```

Comment: Is `sys.stdout` redirected?

Comment: Actually - is it possible that there are no more newlines in the file after that? You could run out of memory if a single line took more than (your RAM) bytes.

Comment: The standard Unix tool `wc` may be informative.

Comment: Instead of `print(i, repr(line))`, maybe try `print(f0.read(1000)); break`.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode: Thanks. I tried and see: `b'263,7449658092300,6998.258682,7449.502713\r\n423,7449658212000,6998.258682,7449.502713\r\n1786,7449658285900,699\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\` and then a Memory Error.

The `\x00` character continues, not sure what that is? Is there a way to determine if there is some useful data after several trailing `\x00`?

Comment: Still a memory error? Did you put the `break` there so it didn't try another loop iteration? I guess the zeros are supposed to indicate the end of data, but some reading part disagrees. I'd say put that code and output in your question as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could inspect what's going on at certain lines with:

```
head -n 32671364 | tail -n 1
```

or with sed as indicated in [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/133692/how-to-display-certain-lines-from-a-text-file-in-linux).

There might be something fishy on that line which breaks repr, thus causing the memory error.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there a windows version of your answer? The one you mentioned works on linux?

Comment: @nuki
Here're the [powershell equivalents](https://luyentap.blogspot.com/2017/09/head-and-tail-command-with-powershell.html)